# How can I export a DataTable to multiple Excel files?

Tags: excel, vb.net, datatable

I have a DataTable in VB.NET with the following data:

[image: DataTable data]

Now I want to export the data to Excel using VB.NET but I need an Excel file for each different id in the last column. I tried to do it but I always get 1 Excel file with all the data in it, instead of 8 different files. Can you help?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51155286/edit) your question and show us your code so we can tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This site is for asking "what i wrong with what I have"... it is **not** for asking "please do it for me?".  As already requested, show us what you already have, and maybe somebody will help. Please read the [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something similar in the "daily chores" application I built for myself.  I'm writing the `DataTable` to separate text files, but the basic premise should be the same.  Similar to what @NeverHopeless proposed, I've set up a separate method to actually produce the file(s) I need so that I can loop through the `DataTable` and, for each unique ID, I execute this method.  The following is obviously very simplified and would need to be modified to fit your requirements, but the basic elements should all be there:

```
Dim MyData As DataTable = GetMyData()
Dim tempdossier As String = Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffffzz")

For Each Row As DataRow In MyData.Rows
    If Not IsDBNull(Row("dossiersoort")) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row("dossiersoort").ToString) Then
        If Row("dossiersoort").ToString <> tempdossier then
            Dim dossierrows() As DataRow

            dossierrows = MyData.Select("dossiersoort = '" & Row("dossiersoort").ToString & "'")
            CreateExcelFile(dossierrows)
        End If

        tempdossier = Row("dossiersoort").ToString
    Else
        tempdossier = Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffffzz")
    End If
Next Row
```

The `tempdossier` variable is just there to help prevent it from creating duplicate files.  I use the "timestamp" value (taken out to the ten-thousandth of a second) as a somewhat reliable way to get a unique value in the case of empty data.

The `CreateExcelFile` method would basically create an empty Excel file, then loop through the `DataRows` in your array (which should only be the ones with the same `dossiersoort` value) to populate the file.  From your OP, it sounds like you already know how to actually create/populate the file, so I won't go into that.  You can easily loop through the array with a simple `For...Next` loop using an `Integer` value (`For dossier As Integer = 0 To dossierrows.GetUpperBound(0)` or something).

This method could be a `Function` returning a `Boolean` value or a `File.IO` object to ensure that the Excel file was actually created properly, or a simple `Sub` with the validation happening after it returns execution to the calling method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`EPPlus`](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus), it even has a method to export it from a `DataTable`. `ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);`

You get the tables with LINQ:

```
Dim allTableList As List(Of DataTable) = yourTable.AsEnumerable().
    GroupBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of Int32)("Dossiersort")).
    Select(Function(rowGrp) rowGrp.CopyToDataTable()).
    ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Steps you can follow:**

- Fetch the required data in the DataTable.
- Find the distinct ids and add them into an array.
- Iterate through this array.
- On each iteration, **either** add a sheet in the Workbook **or** create a completely new WorkBook at a certain location and use the first sheet. (as per your requirement)
- Filter the DataTable using the id you find during iteration.
- Write the filtered data into the sheet.
- Repeat for all the distinct ids.